# How to properly redirect login failure on a spring security login for a failed role?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm configuring an API and web tandem and I want to set up a separated login for security:

1. **API** is accessed without session maintaining and **basic authorization**, method control access.
2. **Web**: for management and backend purposes, authenticated **intercepting URL patterns**: it lands on a **public page** and then the **other** URLs need to be **authenticated and with an ADMIN role** to be accessed and maybe some with USER role through the **login form**.

I think that I'm near to achieving it (testing on browser and API testing sofware requests) but the configuration that I post below fails at this:

At web form login if I put an user credential I'm redirected to error but not to the URL that performs logout as it does with an unknown credentials.

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //super.configure(http);

            http
                 .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                 .csrf().disable()
                 .antMatcher("/api/**")
                 .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                 .httpBasic()

//               .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
        }

    } //FIN CONF API

    // MULTIPLES CONFIGURACIONES. SI HACE MATCH POR ORDEN NO SE APLICAN LAS SIGUIENTES.
    @Configuration
    @Order(2) //Sin @Order lo convierte en el ultimo en ser tenido en cuenta.
    public static class WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/sorteo/**", "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // ZONA PARA ROL CONCRETO
                    //.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()//.hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")//.hasAuthority("TAL1") // CUALQUIERA CON CUENTA
                    .antMatchers("/", "**/favicon.ico", "/resources/static/**").permitAll() //PARTE PUBLICA
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .permitAll()
                    .failureUrl("/salirpafuera")
                    //.failureForwardUrl("/salirpafuera")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/salirpafuera")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
    } // FIN CONF WEB
```

This 2 static clases are inside my: `@EnableWebSecurity public class CentralSecurityConfiguration {`

The api methods are correctly annotated with `Secure` and `PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`

UPDATE: The question may be clarified with this schema:

- If user logins and doesn't have the proper role I want to move him to logout url (which deletes the session and redirects to root url). Now I get to generic error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If user logins and doesn't have the proper role I want to move him to logout url (which deletes the session and redirects to root url). Now I get to generic error page.

In general, you should seek to avoid exposing a logout page as a GET request, therefore redirecting to logout isn't recommended.

- [Additional reading on Logout and CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-considerations-csrf-logout)

However, If I'm understanding your problem correctly, I believe you're receiving a 403 error when logging in successfully as a regular user after visiting an authenticated route that requires admin privileges (e.g. `/admin/dashboard`). This is because an access denied error is distinct from an authentication failure.

Whether you want to redirect to logout or consider switching to an HTTP POST for normal logout, you will need to implement a custom `AccessDeniedHandler`, which can re-use the default `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`.

```
http
    // ...
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new LogoutAccessDeniedHandler("/")); // Redirect to root after logout
```

The `LogoutAccessDeniedHandler` would look something like this:

```java
private static class LogoutAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    // Default handler does an internal forward to a specified URL
    private final AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();

    // CompositeLogoutHandler to perform logout activities like normal logout would
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler = new CompositeLogoutHandler(
            new CookieClearingLogoutHandler("JSESSIONID"),
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler(),
            new LogoutSuccessEventPublishingLogoutHandler()
    );

    public LogoutAccessDeniedHandler(String errorPage) {
        accessDeniedHandler.setErrorPage(errorPage);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logoutHandler.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
    }

}
```

[This diagram](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter) of how Spring Security handles exceptions may be helpful.